# Resize Issue in DataGroup in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, resize, flex4, flash-builder, flex4.5

I am working on Flex 4.6 web application. I have a DataGroup which has custom itemRenderer with horizontal layout. The DataGroup placed in the panel which is resizable. Now when I resize the panel I am increasing the height of itemRenderer to increase the DataGroup height but the problem is when I increase the height of itemRenderer it increases the contentHeight of the DataGroup and then I go back to resize it itemRenderer height decreasing but contentHeight doesn't change that's by scroll is coming if it has less data.

The code is following:

```
<s:DataGroup id="dgStationId" width="100%" height="100%" maxWidth="25000" maxHeight="25000" dataProvider="{dp}" 
                             itemRenderer="DateRenderer">
                    <s:layout>
                        <ronsByDate:SimpleHorizontalLayout useVirtualLayout="true" clipAndEnableScrolling="false" verticalScrollPosition="0"/>
                    </s:layout>        
                </s:DataGroup>
```

And the resize function is :

```
protected function resizeHandler(event:ResizeEvent):void
            {               
                if(ronsConfigId.width > 0 && this.height > MINIMIZED_HEIGHT && (this.height >= this.minHeight || this.width >= this.minWidth))
                {   
                    dgStationId.minHeight = this.height - 305;
                    gpCalenderId.minHeight = this.height - 80;
                    gpCalenderId.width = this.width - (ronsConfigId.width + 38);

                    for(var j:int =0 ; j< dp.length ; j++)
                    {
                        (dgStationId.getElementAt(j) as DateRenderer).minHeight = this.height - 310;                    
                    }               

                    trace("dgStationId.contentHeight : " + dgStationId.contentHeight);                  
                }               
            }
```

If Data is less in the list before resize it look like it:

[image]

After Resize and go back to the initial state of panel scroll is coming in the datagroup:

[image]

The black rectangle of item is inside the itemRenderer.
How can i solve this problem ??